# ORM removes duplicates. But not everywhere

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am making some DB query via repository (ORM), I want to get a list of objects.

What's my problem?
I have two methods in the repository: `getList()` to get a list and `getCount()` to get the number of total records for information.
`getList()` gives me 5 records, and `getCount()` gives the number 9.

```
    public function getList($criteria, $page, $limit, $orderBy, $joins = [])
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select('a');
        if(!empty($joins)) {
            $qb = $this->setCriteriaByJoins($qb, $joins);
        }
        $qb = $this->setCriteriaToQuery($qb, $criteria);

        foreach($orderBy as $order) {
            $qb->addOrderBy('a.' . $order[0], $order[1]);
        }
        if($page && $limit) {
            $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
            $qb->setFirstResult($offset)
                ->setMaxResults($limit);
        }

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $result;
    }
    public function getCount($criteria = [], $joins = []) {
        try {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select('count(a.id)');
            if(!empty($joins)) {
                $qb = $this->setCriteriaByJoins($qb, $joins);
            }
            $qb = $this->setCriteriaToQuery($qb, $criteria);
            $result = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $result = 0;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

In debugging, I see that the `getList()` request was built like this:

```
SELECT r0 _. * FROM film r0_ LEFT JOIN person_film r1_ ON (r0_.id = r1_.film_id) WHERE r1_.person_id IN (45793) AND r0_.status = 1 ORDER BY r0_.`release` DESC, r0_.id DESC LIMIT 48
```

and `getCount()`

```
SELECT count (r0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM film r0_ LEFT JOIN person_film r1_ ON (r0_.id = r1_.film_id) WHERE r1_.person_id IN (45793) AND r0_.status = 1
```

Requesting `getList()` from the repository gives me 5 records. However, if I directly ask the database with this query (without ORM), then I will get 9 records. Of these 9 records, 4 are duplicated due to the fact that the `person_film` table can contain more than one record with the same `film_id` and `person_id` (these records differ in other fields). I found that `/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php:hydrateRowData()` removes duplicates.

1. How to do to make the ORM in the `getList()` request return all 9 records, even if they are duplicates?
2. And vice versa. How to do to the `getCount()` to return 5.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like this is the answer to the second question

```
    public function getCount($criteria = [], $joins = [], $distinct = false) {
        try {
            $sq = ($distinct) ? 'count(distinct(a.id))' : 'count(a.id)';
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select($sq);
            if(!empty($joins)) {
                $qb = $this->setCriteriaByJoins($qb, $joins);
            }
            $qb = $this->setCriteriaToQuery($qb, $criteria);
            $result = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $result = 0;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```